# How to display AWS Cognito users in client app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm a beginner to aws and I have a 2 parter question. I have an Ionic app (Angular) and im using the Amplify CLI to create a backend for it. Ive created a cognito user pool and an api endpoint connected to a lambda function. In my html file, i have a table where i want to display all the cognito users along with a add new user button.

I edited my lambda function as follows :

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log("hello")
  var params = {
    UserPoolId: "***",
    AttributesToGet: []
  };

  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      callback(err)        
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      callback(null, data) 
    }
  });
}
```

Question 1: It works but I can only view the response in cloudwatch logs and not on the API endpoint. How can i display all the users in the rest endpoint?? What am I writing wrong?

Question 2: How can i display the user attributes in a html table? And how would i call the api?

I'm sorry if this is basic but I'm clueless and still learning how the cloud stack works with the client application. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the link! But could you point me to a more example based answer? I'm looking to get started and I'm not getting a direct approach to handling the issues especially on client side

Comment: `callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(data) })`